# Bad performance with hibernate with second level cache when query cache enabled

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

In the application I am working on has multiple cachings used along with second level caching using `ehcache`.

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">ehcache</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS">100</prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

While performing stress test we identified that hibernate performing worst. As you can observe in the below hibernate session takes lot of time, while queries are quick by themselves.

[image]

By digging further into the problem, we found disabling query caching, problem got resolved. To understand why query caching causing the problem, we enabled hibernate debug level logs and found that `TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl` class which is updating time stamps of query spaces is the culprit. Strangely, we are not using query caching on most of the table queries and yet `TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl` doing timestamp invalidation and other stuff for those tables, which is taking a lot of time.

How can I solve this problem? Should I just abandon the query caching and depend on redis for caching?